# What specific problems does Declarative Programming solve best?

Tags: programming-languages, declarative, paradigms

I understand what declarative languages have to offer, but I have not yet connected the dots as to why I would use them. For example, I do not understand why describing a problem is more beneficial than writing a solution to an already understood problem in an imperative language (side-effects non-withstanding).

This is **not** a discussion about what makes a good application in declarative language. I only want to understand the circumstances and any **common, specific project requirements** that would make a programmer say "We really should use a declarative language for this".

Comment: Have you gone through - ? Though it may not completely answer your question, to some extent at least you'll get a basic idea... stackoverflow.com/questions/129628/what-is-declarative-programming

Comment: I saw the question before, so at first I thought you were offering a link for a definition, but then I scrolled down a bit and saw the answer that I assume you guys wanted me to see. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, I guess declarative programming makes sense when there exists multiple strategies to achieve one goal. Declaratively programming the *what* rather than the *how* let the parser/compiler/runtime figure out which strategies is best--it optimizes the execution for you.

Two exemples of declarative languages and optimizations:

- regular expression -- do you really want to bother about the underlying DFA, NDFA that are required for a fast execution?
- SQL queries -- the DBMS has statistics and caches and can (hopefully) figure out an optimal execution plan

The link provided by @verisimilitude is worth reading.

Comment: In the regex examples, even DFAs/NFAs would be somewhat delcarative. Writing out a state machine with loop+switch is the real imperative equivalent, and way worse to do by hand.